# Splitting regions across mountain ranges in 2D tile map partitioning, for a Civ5 mod

Tags: algorithm, maps, lua, modding, spatial-partitioning

I'm trying to do a rewrite of Civ5's `AssignStartingPlots.lua` (Lua is the scripting language used by Civ5), and I'm comfortable writing it, but conceptually, just figuring out *what algorithm* to use, I'm running up against a wall.

By the point that this script is called, the terrain (plains/grassland/desert/snow/jungle/hills, etc.) has already been generated, but the resources have not been placed on it. This script is supposed to 1) place the resources, and 2) assign starting positions to players.

This starts - in the default script as well as in my rewrite - by dividing the map up into "regions" (either Tundra, Jungle, Forest, Desert, Hills, Plains, Grassland or Hybrid), which affect both where certain resources can be placed, and where players are preferentially placed. My general strategy for this is basically flood-fill: pick e.g. a random jungle plot, iterate through its neighbors, and if they 1) are also jungle and 2) are not already in a region, then add them to the region being generated, then go through *their* neighbors and repeat, until every plot has been assigned a region.

One thing I want to add though is having regions be bisected by mountain ranges - that is, e.g. the grassland on the north side of a mountain range should not be placed in the same region as the grassland on the south side of the mountain range, even if they are otherwise simply connected. But this presupposes that 1) I can tell which mountains even *compose* a mountain range in the first place, and 2) how to tell which side of the range a plot falls on.

All the map data is contained in global `Map` object and using `Map.GetPlot(x,y)` I can get a `Plot` object at any (x, y, z = -(x+y) ) on the map. With nested for all x/ all y loops I can interate through every plot on the map, use `Plot.IsMountain()` to check if it's a mountain, and if it is, I can cache it in a table. That gives me a list of all the mountains on the map. And then... what do I do with it to figure out which items collectively compose a range?

And for which side of the range a test plot is on - if the range is perfectly linear then it's as simple as constructing the formula for a secant line from the two most extreme points, and then checking the test plot's y coordinate to see if it's higher/lower of the y-coordinate predicted by the secant y(x). But any curvature in the mountain range (which is almost guaranteed) means the secant line approach is going to end up assigning plots to the wrong side.

Comment: can you give an example map and mark there for example what you would consider (for this mechanics purpose) a mountain range and what not?